# Replace the file data at runtime

Tags: java, replace, symbol-table

I have a text file with a following data

```
a       [variable name]
a=5     [value]
b 
b=8 
c=_x+_y [opertaion]
z
z=3
y
y=4
x
x=1
d=_x+_y+_Z
```

where a,b,c are variables, It may be any alphabets (a-z) depending on user input. On save file operation I want to change the variable names c=_x+y to c=a+b and d=_x+_y+_z to d= z+y+x.....

How can i change the values at run time? how to use symbol table?

Comment: `line = line.replaceAll("_x", "a");`

Comment: The variable may be any one alphabet. Simply i want to replace the value by previous line data.

Comment: is it really that hard to write a simple parser using regex?